# R ggplot How do I choose the colors of a raster with 2 values

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's a simple example of my problem. Steps are 1. create a SpatRaster (terra's version of a raster) with 10 rows, 10 columns and all cell values either 0 or 1. Step 2. Convert to a data frame and rename the columns. Step 3. Create a graph with ggplot. It uses blue and black for the colors and has a continuous legend.

```
library(terra)
x <- rast(nrow=10, ncol=10, xmin=0, xmax=1)
values(x) <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100)
x_df <- as.data.frame(x, xy = TRUE)
names(x_df) <- c("x", "y", "value")
col1 <- c("red", "green")
g <- ggplot(data = x_df, aes(x, y,  fill = value)) +
  geom_tile()
```

Now I'd like to change the colors to those in col1. I have tried putting `colors = col1` in the ggplot aes section and outside it, in an aes in geom_tile, and a few other options. Pretty much all return the error message  `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (100): xxx`.

Converting `value` to a factor solves one problem (the legend is now discrete 0,1) but I still can't figure out where to add code to change the default two colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```r
g <- ggplot(data = x_df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low="red", high="green")
g
```

Comment: This works, but hard wires the colors into scale_fill_gradient. And doesn't work if `value` is a factor. With value as a factor I tried scale_fill_discrete(type = col1). That returns the error  `Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale `

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If `value` is `factor` the values will be discrete in your example (0 or 1) and so you can use `scale_fill_manual(values = c ("red", "green"))`

Comment: Yes! And I can use scale_fill_manual(values = col1)!